# Ruby: Use f.select or f.text_field if "other" is chosen in f.select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need ruby to either take the value from an f.select or an f.text_field if 'other' is chosen in the select form. how is this possible?
in the view:

```
<div class="field">
  Parent</br>
  <% f.label :parent1 %>
  <%= select("jobs","parent1_id",["None","8.5x11","shells"]) %>
  Other:
  <% f.label :parent2 %>
  <%= text_field("jobs","parent2_id") %>
</div>
```

in the controller:

```
def create
  @job = Job.new(params[:job])

    if params[:parent1_id] == "None" #params[:option1_id].nil? #params.has_key?(:option1_id) #Take your pick
        @job.parent = params[:parent2_id]
    else
        @job.parent = params[:parent1_id]
    end

  respond_to do |format|

    if @job.save
      format.html { redirect_to @job, :notice => 'Job was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :json => @job, :status => :created, :location => @job }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json { render :json => @job.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way around the problem would be to use `{:include_blank => "none"}` in the select, and check if its parameter is null in the controller, if it is then use the other parameter.

---

#### How I personally used it:

```
<%= form_for @thing, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  .....
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= select_tag "count", "<option>None</option><option>8.5x11</option><option>shells</option>".html_safe %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= text_field_tag "users" %>
</div>
  ........
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  .......
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Note collection_select is a variation on select where I pass in another model's items.

#### In the controller:

```
def create
.......
  if params[:option1_id] == "" #params[:option1_id].nil? #params.has_key?(:option1_id) #Take your pick
    @thing.attribute = params[:option2_id]
  else
    @thing.attribute = params[:option1_id]
  else
end
```

Comment: could you specify on how to do this or link me to a resource which explains it? I'm extremely new to rails and under a time constraint.

Comment: Updated my answer, it uses collection_select but they are similar. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, how would your text field look?

Comment: exactly the same as a normal text_field with its params set to option2_id

Comment: What exactly is the first param "thing" for the collection select?

Comment: 'thing' is the name of your model as defined with '@thing' in the form_for tag.
My things are consistent at the very least.

Comment: thank you so much. one more thing if you can, now I can't actually get it to save the value in the controller.

Comment: At the end of the controller: '@thing.save'.
If my answer was good and correct, remember you can mark it as a correct answer for others.

Comment: I can't get it to grab the values still. I added code in the main post.

Comment: I've added more code to my example. You can get the params as :users and :count there.